# lambda: what's the output that a lambda function multiply numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, lambda

I am learning ML with python. I read the below code from that book.

```
x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)
x = (x - x.mean()) / x.std()

x0 = np.linspace(-2, 4, 100)

def get_model(deg):
    return lambda input_x=x0: np.polyval(np.polyfit(x, y, deg), input_x)

def get_cost(deg, input_x, input_y):
    return 0.5 * ((get_model(deg)(input_x) - input_y) ** 2).sum()
```

I'm not sure why in the `get_cost` function, the author uses `get_model(deg)` to multiply `input_x` which is `x`. In my understanding, `get_model(deg)` function already return the predicted `y` based on `x0`.

When I tried to understand what's happening, I typed `get_model(4)`, then it returned `<function __main__.get_model.<locals>.<lambda>>`. To my surprised, it haven't returned the predicted `y` based on `x0` but a function?! I just totally messed up.

When I tried typing `get_model(4)(x)`,  It just return the predicted `y` based on `x`, I don't get it. Please someone could help me to figure out.

Comment: That's not multiplication. `get_model` is a function that returns another function.

Comment: @user2357112 that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `get_model(x)` is, as you noticed, not return predictions, but a model for predicting.
If you execute `get_model(1)` the method will return you a linear model, which allows you to fit your values into a linear function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 5)

x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 200)
y = x**2 
y += np.random.rand(len(x)) * 10
x0= x

def get_model(deg):
    return lambda input_x=x0: np.polyval(np.polyfit(x, y, deg), input_x)

linear_model = get_model(1)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.scatter(x, linear_model(), c='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: linear fitting]

If you want to try another model, you can do this by changing the degree of the model:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.scatter(x, get_model(2)(), c='red')
plt.scatter(x, get_model(19)(), c='yellow')

plt.show()
```

[image: other fittings]

I hope this helps you understand the code a bit better.